# How to Increase width of particular column in code behind c #?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to increase width of column that I created in c# my code is,

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Project ID", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(double)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("email", typeof(double)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("description", typeof(double)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ownerdetail", typeof(double)));
DataRow dr;
```

How to set its width? I have found to implement it like,

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", typeof(string))).width;
```

But "*.with*" does not exist then how would we solve it? Hopes for your suggestion thanks in advance

**EDITED:**
How to set Column exist in grid view my code is ,

```
GridViewHcost.DataSource = dset;
```

I try it as help from net,

```
GridViewHcost.Columns.width = 20;
```

But in this command "*.Width*" does not exist. Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: Width of DataTable? I have heard this for the first time. I think there is a confusion with Table

Comment: width of particular column of table

Comment: You need to adjust the UI that you are using to display the data not the DataTable it only holds the data in the back ground.

Comment: i am using this table in grid view

Comment: Then you must adjust the gridview gridview.columns[?].Width I would think or Properties.Width maybe.

Comment: You are talking about GridView yet your example code is about `DataTable` and `DataColumn`. What exactly do you want to extend?

Comment: i wanna extend the width of column title that later on attached to grid view

Answer (score 3):

A [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) is a non-UI class in the .Net framework. This means that there is no "width" for you to change.

So the answer is, **you cannot do it**.

If your `DataTable` is bound to a UI control, then you will need to look at modifying that control instead.

Answer (score 2):

i had same issue,
after add dataTable to your GridView you can change every columns width you want like this:

```
GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Width = 120;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply bind you datatable with datagridview. like:  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; //dt is datatable and then count the number of columns of your datatable and specify the cloumn width for each column using datagridview. like:

```
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
        ID_Column.Width = 200;
```

and so on for all columns..

Answer (score 0):

Width does not exist in `DataTable` object. You can set the Width in a `DataGrid` or `GridView`. `DataTable` is a collection of rows and columns. That's all there is to it.

Both `DataGrid` and `GridView` should have a `Columns` property. If you know how many columns you have and you know exactly which one to extend in width, you can use:

```
var column = GridView.Columns[columnIndex];
column.Width = 150;
```

That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

A datatable is used for in memory storage of data... that data is then typically bound to a gui control such as a dataview, the column of the dataview could then be widened.

[Dataview.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Then you must adjust the gridview gridview.columns[?].Width I would think or Properties.Width maybe.

Answer (score 0):

A DataColumn has no width, do you mean restrict the number of characters in the column via a constraint or affect the display in some way?

If you mean the display, then it depends on how you are outputting the data I.E. If you are you data binding to a GridView, you can override the RowDataBound event and customise the output.

If you mean constrain the field size, then I don't think there is anything built in you can use. I tend to validate the input field length manually before inserting into a database.